# calling rel for anchor from JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net file which call an JS file
the problem is 
when I call anchor property from aspx page it displayed correctly 
but when I tried to call it from js file it works false

my code as
aspx page

```
      <ul id="gallery_id">
                <li class="first">
                    <img src="images/demo/gallery/1.jpg" alt="Title Text" /></li>
                <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 1">
                    <img src="images/demo/gallery/2.jpg" alt="Title Text" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 2">
                    <img src="images/demo/gallery/3.jpg" alt="Title Text" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 3">
                    <img src="images/demo/gallery/4.jpg" alt="Title Text" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/demo/gallery/572x330.gif" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="Image 4">
                    <img src="images/demo/gallery/174x150.gif" alt="Title Text" /></a></li>

            </ul>
```

when I tried to call it dynamically from js file
as

```
 function view_gallery(response) {
        if (response != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    $('#gallery_id').append($('<li id=\"' + response[i].image_guid + '\" class=\"first\" >                        ' +
                            '<img src=\"../images/demo/gallery/' + response[i].image_location + '\" alt=\"' + response[i].image_location + '\" /></li>'));
                }
                else {
                    $('#gallery_id').append($('<li id=\"' + response[i].image_guid + '\">' +


                        '  <a href=\"../images/demo/gallery/' + response[i].image_location+'"'
                        + ' rel=\"prettyPhoto[gallery1]\" title=\"Image 1\">' +

                          ' <img src=\"../images/demo/gallery/' + response[i].image_location
                        + '\" alt=\"Title Text\" /></a></li>'));

                }
```

my asp plugins are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.defaultvalue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fullname, #validemail, #message").defaultvalue("Full Name", "Email Address", "Message");
        $('#shout a').click(function () {
            var to = $(this).attr('href');
            $.scrollTo(to, 1200);
            return false;
        });
        $('a.topOfPage').click(function () {
            $.scrollTo(0, 1200);
            return false;
        });
        $("#tabcontainer").tabs({
            event: "click"
        });
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            theme: 'dark_rounded'
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- prettyPhoto -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/scripts/prettyphoto/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/prettyphoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            theme: 'dark_rounded',
            overlay_gallery: false,
            social_tools: false
        });
    });
</script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/gallery.js"></script>
```

it displayed images but ignores value in rel of anchor element

please help

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting to have happen based on the rel value.  The rel is intended for semantic information, the application doesn't have default behavior associated with it.

Comment: @Paul some plugins used `rel` a lot before `data-` attributes came around. `prettyPhoto` is one of them

Comment: Ah, thanks @charlietfl, didn't pick up on the library.

Comment: @charlietfl , So please any suggestion ?!!!

Comment: when do you initialize plugin?

Comment: @charlietfl .....edited please review

Comment: elements don't exist when you run the plugin code. Check API docs to see if there is an event delegation approach for initializing, or an otherwise you would need to initialize after inserting new elements

Comment: @charlietfl may you be more detailed

Comment: You need to call the plugin function after you insert the html in your `view_gallery()`. You can't apply code to elements that don't exist when the code runs

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry for being as a pain
.... i used   `var plugin=   $.getScript('../layout/scripts/prettyphoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.js');`  in `view_gallrey().`  then in rel proberty used plugin.prettyphoto   but nothing changed :(

Comment: but the script is already loaded. `$("#gallery_id a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({...})`